# How to run a function on each subset of a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset, fuzzy-comparison

**The data**

I have a dataframe in R with the following sort of structure:

```
ID   Type  Group           Text
100    A     1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
103    A     1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
105    A     1    consectetur adipiscing eli
106    A     1    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
107    B     1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
209    B     1    Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli
300    C     1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
501    C     1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
503    A     2    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
711    A     2    consectetur adipiscing eli
799    B     2    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
811    B     2    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
812    C     3    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
820    C     3    Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli
831    C     3    sed do eiusmod temporo eli
```

Which can be reproduced with this code:

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  "ID" = c(100, 103, 105, 106, 107, 209, 300, 501, 503, 711, 799, 811, 812, 820, 831),
  "Type" = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  "Group" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  "Text" = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing eli', 'et dolore magna aliqua. Ut', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing eli', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli', 'sed do eiusmod temporo eli')
)
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to write a function that does the following:

- Go over all the rows in the dataframe and identify all the subsets in the sample based on a cross of 'Type' and 'Group' (e.g. A1, A2, B1, B2...)
- For each subset, compare all the texts within that subset.
- Then, identify texts that are highly similar (i.e. duplicates), move them to a separate dataframe (all duplicates should end up in the same dataframe, regardless of subset), and then remove them from the original dataframe.

Basically, the function should identify highly similar texts within each subset, by running on one subset at a time.

**What I have so far**

The following code allows me to run this calculation on the whole dataframe, with no subsetting:

```
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)

temp_var <- stringdistmatrix(test_df$Text, test_df$Text) # Calculate similarities

temp_var <- which((temp_var <= 10), arr.ind = TRUE) # Identify texts with 10 or fewer differences (i.e. duplicates)
temp_var <- as.data.frame(temp_var)
temp_var <- temp_var %>%
  filter(temp_var$row != temp_var$col) # Removes cases where a text is compared with itself

x <- temp_var[,1]
x <- unique(x) # Create list of row numbers of duplicate texts

duplicate_texts <- test_df[x, ] # Save the duplicate texts
test_df_2 <- test_df[!test_df$ID %in% duplicate_texts$ID,] # Remove the duplicate texts from the original dataframe
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to run this code on one subset of the sample at a time.

The original dataframe is quite large, and has hundreds of subsets, several hundreds of thousands of files, and significantly longer texts, so subsetting is necessary. In addition, I need to delete or overwrite the previous similarity matrix each time I calculate a new one, since their size gets quite large.

Comment: Write a function that takes a data frame as an argument (for just one subset) and does your calculation. Test on a little subset. Then you do `your_data %>% group_by(Type, Group) %>% group_map(your_function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach this problem. You don't necessarily need to resort to mapping here, since the problem isn't actually dataframe-in, dataframe-out (the only input is the `Text` vector in each subset). This means we can simply use a grouped filter to obtain either of the dataframes of interest (uniques or duplicates).

```r
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)
test_df <- data.frame(
  "ID" = c(100, 103, 105, 106, 107, 209, 300, 501, 503, 711, 799, 811, 812, 820, 831),
  "Type" = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  "Group" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  "Text" = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing eli', 'et dolore magna aliqua. Ut', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing eli', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli', 'sed do eiusmod temporo eli'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

The key thing to realise is that `group_by` will expose only a section of the vector to whatever function we use later, so we need to write a function that accepts a vector in. We want it to return `TRUE` if a string is too similar to any of the other elements in the vector, so we use `apply` with `any` to check each row for this condition. We have to make sure we first get rid of the diagonal elements to avoid self-comparison. This is also a good time to parameterise `threshold`.

```r
any_string_duplicates <- function(text_vector, threshold = 10) {
  mat <- stringdistmatrix(text_vector, text_vector)
  mat <- mat < threshold
  diag(mat) <- NA # Simpler way to remove self-comparisons
  apply(mat, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Now the duplicate values and the unique values can easily be retrieved with a grouped `filter`.

```r
test_df %>% # Duplicates
  group_by(Type, Group) %>%
  filter(any_string_duplicates(Text))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   Type, Group [5]
#>       ID Type  Group Text                      
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>                     
#>  1   100 A         1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  2   103 A         1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  3   107 B         1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  4   209 B         1 Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli
#>  5   300 C         1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  6   501 C         1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  7   799 B         2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  8   811 B         2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#>  9   812 C         3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#> 10   820 C         3 Lorem ipsum dolor sing eli

test_df %>% # Uniques
  group_by(Type, Group) %>%
  filter(!any_string_duplicates(Text))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   Type, Group [3]
#>      ID Type  Group Text                      
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>                     
#> 1   105 A         1 consectetur adipiscing eli
#> 2   106 A         1 et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
#> 3   503 A         2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#> 4   711 A         2 consectetur adipiscing eli
#> 5   831 C         3 sed do eiusmod temporo eli
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>